# How to draw vertical Bars with dygraphs

Tags: javascript, r, dygraphs, r-dygraphs

I use R implementation of `dygraphs` to generate interactive charts in R. By default, it plots *line chart* of supplied data. However I would like to have *vertical bars* instead of line chart for below data -

```
library(dygraphs)
dygraph(mdeaths)
```

Appreciate if someone can give me any pointer to implement the same, as I failed to find any option to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try `dyBarChart`

```
library(dygraphs)
dyBarChart(dygraph(mdeaths))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but if I zoom in, then days of months are coming into, which should not be the case

Comment: Looks like in-built functionality of `dygraph`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Dygraphs plotters plugin. Have a look at below links for the implementation of Dygraphs Bar Chart implementation.

> https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/master/tests/plotters.html#L97
>   http://dygraphs.com/tests/plotters.html

Maybe it can help you.